# Rainbox library - how can I set no/default background colour on a Cell?

Tags: haskell

When using a `Cell` how can I set no background colour?

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rainbox-0.18.0.10/docs/Rainbox-Core.html#t:Cell

```
Cell
  :: Data.Sequence.Internal.Seq
       (Data.Sequence.Internal.Seq
          (Rainbow.Types.Chunk Data.Text.Internal.Text))
     -> Alignment Horizontal
     -> Alignment Vertical
     -> Rainbow.Types.Radiant
     -> Cell
```

Alternatively is there some way I can determine the terminal's default background color? How would I then create a `Radient` type with this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a 'default' text without additional color formatting:

```
import Rainbow.Types

defaultText :: Rainbow.Radiant
defaultText = Radiant (Color Nothing) (Color Nothing)
```

Comment: This was flagged and came up in review, you might consider adding a bit of explanation